# Laravel 5 mass bulk import 3000000 records/items

Tags: laravel

I have an array with 3000000 items from a csv file.

Now i can import this into the dbase like this.

Is this the fastest and best way?

Or is there a better solution?

```
$items = [
    0 => array(
        'id' = 1,
        'x_id' = 2,
        'y_id' = 3,
        'date' = '2018-02-20',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' = 1,
        'x_id' = 2,
        'y_id' = 3,
        'date' = '2018-02-20',
    ),
    etc etc
];

DB::table('items')->insert($items);
```

Comment: maybe chunk will do (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#chunking-results)

Comment: If you use MySQL, it is better to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` or `mysqlimport` from command line.

Comment: @arunkumar can you please give the answer, i am going to use chunks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel chunk will work on collection, so change your items array to collection:

```
$items = collect($items);
```

Make chunk of your choice

```
$chunks = $items->chunk(100);
```

Then do a foreach and insert by 100 each time

```
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    DB::table('items')->insert($chunk->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are too many records either PHP script will time out or it will eat all the memory.

I will suggest creating a background job will serve the purpose.

```
php artisan make:job
```

then run the job `php artisan queue:work`

Answer (score 0):

You can use chunk but i will perfer to use cron job for it. Make job which will execute in background process.